# Parse XML with generic tags using Batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file

First post, so sorry if this is a repeat. After looking around a bit I'm not finding any pre-existing answer that suits my needs.

I need to build a batch file that can parse an XML file that looks, in part, something like this:

```
<parameter>
    <name>description</name>
    <value>something something</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <name>project</name>
    <value>ProjectName</value>
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <name>email group to notify</name>
    <value>EmailGroup</value>
</parameter>
```

I want to find the value associated with the "Project" parameter. I'm able to get the word "Project" with the below `for` statement (`:job` outputs it to a text file without the `<name>` tags), but I can't figure out how to get it parse the next line where the value is located.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i /c:"<name>project</name>" output.xml') do call :job "%%i"
```

Comment: [XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s01.html) is a command line tool for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get the number of the line with the "Project" parameter:
for /F "delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /N /I /C:"<name>project</name>" output.xml') do set "line=%%i"

rem Get the value of 3rd. token in next line:
for /F "skip=%line% tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in (output.xml) do set "value=%%a" & goto continue
:continue

echo Value of Project: "%value%"
call :job "%value%"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's generally more graceful to parse and manipulate XML as XML, rather than as text to scrape and tokenize. That way you aren't so dependent upon anticipating the formatting of the files you're manipulating -- line breaks in the middle of tags, for example. To that end, I suggest that you employ Windows Scripting Host and use the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` COM object to manipulate the XML DOM.

The following batch + JScript hybrid example should be saved with a .bat extension.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "XMLfile=test.xml"
set "XPath=//name[contains(text(),'project')]/../value/text()"

for /f %%I in (
    'cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%XMLfile%" "/x:%XPath%"'
) do set "projectName=%%I"

echo %projectName%

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera

String.prototype.trim = function() { return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); };
var DOM = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    args = { file: WSH.Arguments(0), XPath: WSH.Arguments.Named('x') };

DOM.load(args.file);
DOM.async = false;
DOM.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

if (DOM.parseError.errorCode) {
    var e = DOM.parseError;
    WSH.StdErr.WriteLine('Error in ' + args.file + ' line ' + e.line + ' char '
        + e.linepos + ':\n' + e.reason + '\n' + e.srcText);
    WSH.Quit(1);
}

var node = DOM.documentElement.selectSingleNode(args.XPath);
WSH.Echo(node.data.trim());
```

Comment: Thanks rojo! I ended up going the pure batch way of doing it, but there are some neat ideas here that I'll definitely be learning from.